# SO_TIMESTAMP for tsc not timeval?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

As can be seen in the [socket man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket), one can use `SO_TIMESTAMP` with `setsockopt` to 
measure the amount of time it takes the Linux kernel to hand a received network packet off to user space.

There is a good description of this functionality here: [Measuring latency in the Linux network stack between kernel and user space](http://vilimpoc.org/research/ku-latency/).

Is there any way to get a reading of the `tsc` rather than a `timeval` at the time the kernel received a packet?

Comment: If you take many samples you will have sub-us accuracy anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

- It's platform-specific.
- The TSC can change frequency on some (P4-era) processors and has historically not been synchronized between cores (some modern CPUs synchronize it between cores in the same package).
- Ideally you'd want the packet to be timestamped by the network card anyway; [PTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) typically requires this to achieve its target accuracy.

The most you can reasonably ask for is a `struct timespec` in the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` timebase. I don't think it exists, but it would not be too difficult to add.